# Archive Accounts

Tags: trigger, account, schedulebatch, duplicate-management, archive

What is the best way to archive accounts, after we have identified them as obsolete. ?

I want to automate the process of archiving the obsolete accounts.

These accounts become obsolete under two circumstances -

1. Duplicates as identified by the sales team. On Account there is a text field called ClientID which is defined as external ID, Unique.
   The sales team types XXXX to indicate this record is obsolete
2. Accounts that are bought out i.e sold to new owners.

My approach is this -

1. Create a checkbox 'Archived'
2. Create a workflow that will make the value true based on a criteria
3. Move the record with Archived value == true to a Custom Object called 'Archived Accounts'

What i don't know is how it will affect relationships? like contacts, opportunities, and anything else that i am missing.

Can someone guide me?

Thanks !

Comment: You are not necessarily archiving accounts here but only moving them to a different object. Your data will still continue to use data storage. What you need here is account merges to remove any redundant data.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be overcomplicating this functionality by not looking to Salesforce platform idioms to guide your process development.

Duplicate accounts should generally not be archived; they should be merged. Merges reparent all relationships from the "losing" records to the "winning" record, ensuring your data hierarchy retains its integrity. Using merges makes sure that your users can rely on a single, canonical record, even if they perform a global SOSL search (which you can't limit to exclude your "archived" records).

Accounts that are bought out can be merged just like duplicates, or you can make them part of an Account hierarchy (i.e., make them child accounts) if they retain an independent nature, or you can use a field like a "Status" to mark them as no longer valid. While this will be fairly dependent upon your business process, there's lots of approaches that will be more native and easier to implement and navigate than trying to copy the records into a different custom object to archive them.

You can use native [Salesforce Duplicate Management](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/sales_admin_duplicate_management) to help your organization detect and remediate duplicate records.

Comment: Thankyou for the response.I agree about merging. I have duplicate rule and potential duplicate component. But this solution allows only manually merging accounts. My challenge is automating the process of merging accounts. Our accounts are created from Web or through a daily import from an external system. There are situations where the account that got created from web, already exists in salesforce. In that situation I want to automatically merge the accounts, but strip the PDF from the account that was created from web and merge it into the already existing account. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you cannot change the import flow, which is the source of the problem, I would recommend evaluating 3rd-party duplicate management software.

Answer (score 0):

What if you create a checkbox named `Active` or whatever you want on the Account object. Then you could just create a list view to show only the active accounts. This way you wont need to create another object and they can all stay in Account?

I agree that using a workflow to check this checkbox would be a good idea. Also I would suggest creating duplicate/matching rules to merge duplicate accounts

Comment: Thanks Zack. my challenge is automatically merging duplicates.

Comment: That is one of our issues as well. Using the duplicate/matching rules will allow you to merge duplicate records when they are found. I think this would be the best direction to go.